# Tailwind @applying custom classes generates incorrect styles

Tags: css, tailwind-css, postcss

In one file, I have `typography.css`:

```css
.p.xl {
  font-size: 1.375rem;
}

.p.lg {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.p {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
}

.p.sm {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}
```

And in another file, I want to apply `.p.lg` to my `.link`s:

```css
.link {
  @apply p lg;
}
```

The following code is generated and shipped to the front end:

```css
.link {
    font-size: 1.125rem;
}
```

Even if I change the order of `lg` and `p` and even if I inline it in the link itself with `class="p lg"`.

---

Hell, even if I specify for the `p` styles to explicitly NOT target the `lg` elements it STILL generates the incorrect CSS:

Input:

```css
.p.xl {
  font-size: 1.375rem;
}

.p.lg {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.p:not(.xxl):not(.xl):not(.lg):not(.sm):not(.xs):not(.xxs) {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
}

.p.sm {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}
```

Output:

```
.link:not(.xxl):not(.xl):not(.lg):not(.sm):not(.xs):not(.xxs) {
    font-size: 1.125rem;
}
```

It's just stupidly copying and pasting the rest of the paragraph selector rather than running the selector logic and determining whether or not to apply the styles.

I have this exact same problem hundreds of times in my project with seemingly no solution other than to completely abandon Tailwind for half the project or to install `tailwind-plugins` and then enter every single combination of every class I want to apply in my `tailwind.config.js`.

Help is greatly appreciated. I've searched online for a while without finding anyone even having the same problem; I only found people who don't know how `@apply` works (well perhaps I'm one of them...). Thanks in advance.

---

#### UPDATE:

I also have:

```css
.p {
  @apply font-light;
}

.p.subheading {
  @apply font-normal;
}
```

And of course the same issue with applying `p subheading` where it applies the wrong font weight and even using `.p:not(.subheading)` still generates the wrong styles. Will I really have no way whatsoever of styling `p` font-weights without also giving every single `.p` ANOTHER class to tell it to use one font weight? In other words, are default styles impossible?

---

#### UPDATE 2

Even when using `!important` it still fails to override...

```css
  .p {
    @apply font-light;
  }

  .p.subheading {
    @apply !font-normal;
  }
```

and

```css
  .p.xl {
    font-size: 1.375rem !important;
  }

  .p.lg {
    font-size: 1.25rem !important;
  }

  .p {
    font-size: 1.125rem;
  }

  .p.sm {
    font-size: 0.875rem !important;
  }
```

I STILL get the wrong font sizes and font weights generated:

```css
.link {
    font-size: 1.125rem;
}
.link {
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

Comment: I think you don't understand what's going on. what you posted is the correct behavior of tailwind. .link { @ apply p lg; } will apply what you have for a class called .p and a separate class called .lg   As shown,  this makes the font size 1.125 rem. If you are wanting to use 1.25rem then you need to use .link { @ apply p-lg }

Comment: @Kwright02 Thanks for the comment. I run into this as well for font-weight, even when I specify `:not`. Will I have to change all of the naming conventions across the project so there are zero defaults that are overridden? Is it literally impossible in tailwind to override a default style?

Comment: you can override like this: @aply !custom-style  this works like !important in regular css

Comment: Oh thanks, I'll try that! And just use `!important` in the vanilla CSS lines. Doesn't seem ideal, but it'll work. Thanks

Comment: Still doesn't work @Kwright02 it's still giving me the wrong font sizes and font weights. Will update my answer momentarily.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's against the rules, but I'd help you out in a discord call if you have it

Comment: Sure, if you wouldn't mind, I'd appreciate it! I'll chat you my discord

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250693/discussion-between-justin-and-kwright02).

Comment: I think you're trying to apply logic that is completely out of Tailwind's scope. I believe all your attempts will doom to failure unless you change approach